# HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false); asp.net MVC security issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

In my asp.net MVC appplication i have below line of code in default.cs page which is present by default and every ASP.NET MVC application should have this line.

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false);
```

Now the issue is Ounce is reporting that is security issue saying CrossSiteScripting.Reflected .. 
Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a security breach at all. All this code does is ensure that the current request is re-issued using MVC's request handler, instead of ASP.NET's. This code exists to handle cases where MVC fails to handle the request by default as a result of the server's configuration.

It sounds to me like Ounce is reporting a false positive.

Comment: Thanks for reply Nathan, Even though i commented that my website os working fine . Could you please provide me some sort of example/url ? that would be very helpfull

Comment: @prakash If I am not mistaken, so long as your application is running on IIS 7.x in integrated mode then the Default.aspx logic is not needed. In some environments when the user requests 'www.website.com/' they will be auto-redirected to '/Default.aspx', rather than to your default route. The code in the included Default.aspx simply ensures that the user ends up at the correct MVC-handled address.

Comment: The Default.aspx file was only needed to make [OutputCache] work correctly for MVC 1 applications running on IIS 6.  If you're using MVC 2+ (any IIS version) or MVC 1 on IIS7, it's not necessary.  Go ahead and delete it. :)